# How to configure application inside the apache2 and application running on windows tomcat server

Tags: apache2

As per mentioned in title, my applications are running in two different windows server with different ports so i want perfect configuration for this achievement.

Here Apache2 is running on ubuntu server and he act as a Reverse Proxy Server.

**Windows Server Application running on tomcat details:**

```
1) <http://www.example.com/sit> running on http://10.0.120.1:7070/
2) <http://www.example.com/uat> running on http://10.0.120.1:6060/
3) <http://www.example.com/cug> running on http://10.0.130.1:7070/
4) <http://www.example.com/staging> running on http://10.0.130.1:6060/
```

**Please find image link where we added my apache2 configuration for your information:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4F7r.png)

**After this configuration while accessing my application is not working. please check and suggest best practices for me.**